# как изменять тэги mp3 трека

Tags: java

Подскажите как изменять тэги mp3 трека? Я нашел библиотеку тут http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/ Собственно хотел бы использовать ее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic), к примеру:

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
ID3v1 id3v1Tag;
if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
  id3v1Tag =  mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
} else {
  // mp3 does not have an ID3v1 tag, let's create one..
  id3v1Tag = new ID3v1Tag();
  mp3file.setId3v1Tag(id3v1Tag);
}
id3v1Tag.setTrack("5");
id3v1Tag.setArtist("An Artist");
id3v1Tag.setTitle("The Title");
id3v1Tag.setAlbum("The Album");
id3v1Tag.setYear("2001");
id3v1Tag.setGenre(12);
id3v1Tag.setComment("Some comment");
mp3file.save("MyMp3File.mp3");
```

Comment: спасибо, попробуем так

Comment: Почему может вылезать ошибка при `new Mp3File("1.mp3")` `throws IOException, UnsupportedTagException, InvalidDataException`?